# Cannot set Form.Left to a negative value in FormShow

Tags: delphi-7

I am trying to "move" a form around in the FormShow event, using Delphi 7.  It seems that if I assign a negative number to Form.Left, that number becomes zero.  I am trying to get a form to appear on the leftmost monitor, which has negative X values.  Are there conditions under which Delphi or Windows will force Left to be non-negative?  DefaultMonitor is dmDesktop, FormStyle is fsNormal, OldCreateOrder is TRUE, Position is poDefault, WindowState is wsNormal.

Also, while the form is fairly small at design time, it is maximized at run-time, even though I can find no place where the WindowState is altered, nor any place which uses "max".

Comment: Given what you've said, there's no reason why the form should be maximized or why Left shouldn't be negative.  The form being maximized may be the source of the problem with Left.  When a form is maximized, you have no control over Left, Top, Width or Height.   Do you believe the value of Left is zero because the form is pressed against the left side of the screen, or have you actually looked at its value?   What is the value of Left after the window is normalized(un-maximized)?  And can you tell us what BorderStyle is set to?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I agree if I'm trying to modify Left after the form is Maximized, that would explain the problem.  I display a ShowMessage before and after assigning the negative value to Left, so I know it is zero. BorderStyle is bsSizeable. At the time of the assignment, WindowState is wsNormal.

Comment: Note that this form is invoked from within a DLL.  We pass the main form handle into the DLL, but forms running from a DLL often behave strangely.

Comment: I cannot even alter the window position as the first statement in the FormCreate event when the WindowState is wsNormal.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Is it possible Align is set alClient?  I thought it was odd that you said the window state was maximized and Left=0.  When I tried that, I got Left = -8.  If the window state is normal, but Align is set to alClient, then Left is zero.   You speak of a main form.  Is this form a child form?  You say the code is in a DLL.  Do you have the same problem when the same code is in the main program?  It's difficult to help from a vacuum.  Could you provide enough source code to duplicate the problem?

Comment: You found the problem.  The code was using alClient rather than wsMaximize!  alClient seems to always force the window to the primary monitor, but wsMaximize works as one would hope.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I'll write it up as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Align is set to alClient.

This will force the window to fill the screen even if WindowState is wsNormal.

One clue is that Left is zero.  When a window is maximized, if it has the default border of bsSizeable, Left will be -8, (depending on your Windows display settings.)